# setIntervalを使用するとコールバック毎にメモリが増えていく

Tags: javascript

Monacaで空のプロジェクトを作成し、下記のjavascriptを実行しました。

```
  setItv();
  function setItv() {
    setInterval(function(){
    }, 5000);
  }
```

これをメモリ監視すると、5秒ごとに階段状にいつまでもメモリが積もっていきました。
MonacaでのsetIntervalの仕様なのでしょうか？
それともsetIntervalはこのようなものなのでしょうか。

【追記】
確認環境は Android 4.4.4 (402SH) です。

【補足】
Monaca以外の環境でも現象を確認しましたので、monacaタグを取り、javascriptととしての質問に変更させていただきます。
1.5分を過ぎたころからGCが一切動かな‌​くなり、数分ごとにメモリが階段状に増えていきます。

確認環境は、
Monacaデバッガー + Android 4.4.4 (402SH)
Monacaでのデバッグビルドapk + Android 4.4.4 (402SH)
Cordova6.2.0でのビルドapk + Android 4.4.4 (402SH)
PC(win7) + chrome

Comment: 再現する環境を質問に追記すると回答が付きやすいかも知れません。（手元のAndroid環境では再現しませんでした。）

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。確認環境を追記しました。

Comment: 上記コメントですが、再現しなかったのはCordova(6.2.0)でビルドした物です。これは仮想環境(Genymotion)のAndroid 4.4.4 でも再現しませんでした。Monacaには独自の問題があるかもしれませんね。

Comment: コメントを受けてMonacaを使用せずCordova6.2.0でビルドしてみましたが、やはり同様の現象が確認できました。1.5分を過ぎたころからGCが一切動かなくなり、数分ごとにメモリが階段状に増えていきました。15分ほど監視して頂くと顕著かと思います。また、同様のスクリプトをPCのブラウザ（win7+chrome）でも試してみましたが、やはり長時間放置すると同様にメモリが増えていくようでした。
setIntervalの仕様というより別のところに原因があるのでしょうか。

Comment: 「他のアプリ」は落ちるけれど、このコードは落ちない、という事でしたら、むしろ「問題は`setInterval`には無い事が確認出来た」という事になると思います。このコードで落ちるのか、落ちないのか、は大事な部分ですので、確認された方がよいかと。(メモリがまだ残っている場合はGCをしない処理系もあるでしょうから、問題があるとは限りません。)

Comment: これを実行すれば間違いなく再現しますと言えるコード(HTML+JavaScript)を記載すべきです。

Comment: 厳密な情報でなく失礼いたしました。少なくともサンプルスクリプトでメモリが溜まっていくことは確実なので、「落ちる」という表現を削除いたしました。ただ落ちる落ちないは別としても、メモリが溜まっていく原因を明らかにできればと思っています。

Comment: 導入しているプラグインや、記載しているコード、処理手順などによっても発生するか否か分かれると思いますので発生する完全なコードは共有されたほうが良いかと思います。一番いいのはプロジェクトファイルを最小にしてzipを共有頂ければ他の方も調査しやすいかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。親記事のスクリプトが全てになります。原因を絞りたかったため、必要ない記述はしないようにしてテストしています。ファイルもindex.htmlと、このスクリプトのみを記述した外部jsファイルのみとなっています。

Comment: こういう記事を見つけたのですが、処理が空のタイマーで発生しているんですよね？、処理が遅延した場合でもIntervalは関係なしに次のスレッドに以降するらしいです。 http://d.hatena.ne.jp/sandai/20100513/p1

Comment: ありがとうございます。はい、空のタイマーで発生しています。setIntervalの挙動については把握していまして、ただ次の処理に移行してもメモリが増えていくのが理解できずにいます。減らないが平坦なまま、もしくは一時的に増えるだけ、なのであれば納得なのですが…。空のfunctionであることが何か関係していますか？（明示的にreturnが必要等）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ただ落ちる落ちない‌​は別としても、メモリが溜まっていく原因を明らかにできればと思っています

GCのタイミングは処理系依存ですが、Android(4.4.4)を観察する限り、単純なケースだと下記のどちらかで行なわれる事が多いようです。

- メモリ使用量が閾値を越える
- 暇な（イベントの発生などがない）状態が一定時間続く

質問の状況ですと、メモリの使用量は5秒ごとに関数の実行で多少増えていきますが、閾値にはなかなか達しません。
5秒ごとに`setInterval`がイベントを起しますので、暇になるタイミングもありません。
よって、メモリ使用量が右肩上りで、GCは行なわれない、という状況になります。

これは`setInterval`に限らず起ります。例えば`click`イベントに何もしない関数をバインドし、5秒おきに外部からクリックしてやる事でも再現します。

また、問題になる事でもありません。放っておけばいずれ上記のGCタイミングの「メモリ使用量が閾値を越える」状況になりますのでGCされます。インターバルを5000msではなく100msくらいにして実験すればすぐに観察出来るはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！100msで実験して、GCが動くことを確認できました！動作についてもご説明頂いた内容で納得いたしました。元々のアプリが最終的に落ちてしまう件についてはGCが上手く動かない別の理由がある可能性が高いですね。そちらは別途調査することにします。

Answer (score 0):

`monaca`で`OnsenUI`をつかってますか？
`OnsenUI`は最初にアクセスする`index.html`からブラウザ視点でみると遷移しません。
`index.html`に`ons-page`を読み込み追加して表示します。

ですので、グローバルの`window`にバインドされるタイマーは
`OnsenUI`で`pushPage`で遷移してものこります。

`prePush`や、`prePop`のイベントにバインドし、タイマーをクリアしないと残り続けます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。OnsenUIは使用しておりません。空のプロジェクトに、単純に上記スクリプトを記述したjsファイルを読み込んだだけになります。

Answer (score 0):

自己レスですが、この現象が同じことなのかと思われます。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034107/does-javascript-setinterval-method-cause-memory-leak

リークしているわけではなく、現状そういう仕様である、というのが答えなのかもしれません。

Comment: GapDebugなどでメモリを監視すると上げっぱなしですね。Monacaデバッガーのメモリ使用量表示のみですと、上げ続けるような動きはないです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Monacaのカスタムデバッガーを使用していますが、やはり何度確認しても上がっていきました。